# disable DatePicker if input field is readonly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a problem, with the `DatePicker`.
Basically, I only want it enabled, if a checkbox is checked (Default is disabled).
If I set the `DatePicker` to disabled, I have a problem with saving the TextBox value, across postbacks. So, I have to set the datepicker as enabled, when the page loads.

My idea, as a work-around, was to set min/max date to negatives, meaning you cannot pick any dates. The `DatePicker` will still appear, but at least a date cannot be picked. The problem though, is how do I remove my min/max settings again (when the checkbox is clicked), to enable selection again?

Also, are there any other way to suppres the `DatePicker`?

I don't really know what code I can possibly post, but this is my DatePicker constructor:

```
$("#<%= txtReleasedDate.ClientID %>").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', minDate: -1, maxDate: -2 });
```

What I would like, is a way to remove minDate and maxDate from it again.

Comment: Can you post some code on what you have already?

Comment: I don't really know what code I can show, to help clarify. I don't really do anything, but I have added the part where I create the datepicker, with invalid min/max dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting a hold of my local, jquery expert, he suggested that I read the documentation, where it clearly said, that you could set minDate to null. Oops..

```
$("#<%= txtApprovedDate.ClientID %>").datepicker({ minDate: null });
```